# Why does it show inventor of Patent us2394492 as Elmer Scharenberg with assignee B.F, Goodrich?

Tags: inventorship, us2394492

When the inventor shown at US Patent and Trademark Office website is Millard R. Bell. Bell did assign rights to B.F.Goodrich in June 1942 for $1. I HAVE THE UNCASHED CHECK. Why the discrepancy in the records, when my father, Millard Bell, was obviously the inventor?

Thank you 
Jon Bell
Chandler, AZ
jcbell3@hotmail.com

Comment: I imagine it would take a historian digging in the archives of Goodrich for months to even approach this question. Why again was Bell obviously the inventor? Also, this type of question is officially off-topic here but no harm done.

Comment: A quick search in google patents for Millard R. Bell turns up five inventions of his that were assigned to Goodrich.